# Maven downloads from central though other repo configured and artifact already present

Tags: maven, jenkins

I run a Jenkins build on a server without internet access. All artifacts must be downloaded from a nexus proxy repositories. It goes fine, tens of jars are being downloaded from the proxy, until maven tries to download from central an artifact it has already downloaded. Below some lines of the log:

```
[INFO] Downloading: http://{mynexus}/nexus/content/groups/{myrepo}/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
. . .
[INFO] Downloaded: http://{mynexus}/nexus/content/groups/{myrepo}/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar (278 KB at 3118.6 KB/sec)
. . . 
[INFO] Downloaded: http://{mynexus}/nexus/content/groups/{myrepo}/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar (1467 KB at 23275.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
[WARNING] Failed to getClass for org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo
```

It even doesn't try to check the configured repository first, and the artifact has just been downloaded from the proxy. I wonder what the last two lines mean, this is not the normal 'Could not transfer artifact' failure message. Further down the log:

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar failed: 
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Could not transfer artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.43.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: How does your settings.xml file look like?

Comment: I am not jenkins admin so I don't know. But what settings could cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Such behaviour is caused if you have something like

```
<mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
```

in your settings.xml.

To force maven to use your mirror **and only your mirror**, you must write

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

in your settings.xml

Comment: There is no mirror, the nexus repository is defined in the pom.xml of the project: with <repository>

Comment: Ok, your nexus repository is what I mean by mirror.

Comment: Do not define your mirror in your pom.xml. That is bad practice - it sets your pom's portability to practically zero. Define your mirror in your settings.xml. See also https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html Scroll down to where it says "Using A Single Repository"